# How do I fix Android Studio Error "Cannot access class... Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding, android-safe-args

I am practing how to using SafeArgs and some other kotlin tools.

Even after adding the `SafeArgs` plugin and classpath I still get an error saying..

```
Cannot access class 'com.example.testingtaskmanager.ui.updatefragment.UpdateFragmentArgs'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

Here's the added `SafeArgs` plugin:

```
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
```

Here's the added `SafeArgs` classpath:

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
```

I have even tried the other `SafeArgs` Plugin, it still gave the same result.
Here's the other safeargs I tries to use:

```
id "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```

For clarity, here's a photo of the error;
[image: SafeArgs Error. Cannot access safe args class]

**EDIT;**

more of the plugin from build.gradle App/ Module level

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'


    //
//    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

more of the plugin from build.gradle Project Level

```
dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"

        //
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file.

Comment: @RudraRokaya Thanks for youe feedback, I have added some more buil.gradle file. But exactly do you need, as i don't want the code to be too long and become a turn off.

Comment: can you comment on this line binding.args= args and run your code.?

Comment: Please @RudraRokaya I don't understand what you mean.. Do you mean I should comment out the "binding.args= args" and run the code..

Comment: yes just try to do that.

Comment: @RudraRokaya I will get an error since the SafeArgs is used in the .xml file of the fragment..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242233/discussion-between-rudra-rokaya-and-edwin).

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still has the same problem it's easy to fix it just add this to your build.gradl

```
android {
        .
        .
        .

     buildFeatures{
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            kotlin {
                srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/navigation-args'
            }
        }
    } 
 }
```

Comment: nothing happend

Comment: I'm telling you what's works for me, check other answers

Answer (score 0):

When  i working on project, i faced same error.

I used `dataBinding` and Then the error come same above.

I solved this issue via renaming parent folder name starting with lowercase and Only `ViewModel` Name start with Capital Name .

In my project, i faced this issue due to below

`com.example.example.ui.UserModule.ViewModel.SettingViewModel`

to

`com.example.example.ui.userModule.viewModel.SettingViewModel`